# Does iRig work with old Mac Air 2008 with OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: sound-effects, sound-devices, macbook

I was planning on buying an iRig since it seems to be such a useful little device. Problem is, I have PCs and Android cellphones and tablets--not a big Apple fan. I do have an old Macbook Air 2008 model, the first generation. It has Mac OS X 10.6.8. I was wondering if anyone knows if it would work with my HP laptop PC or the Macbook Air?

PS: I'm thinking of buying the iRig, not the iRig Pro or HD version.